# React select v2 on space press selects first value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

When on Select field I hit space, first value from options is being selected. How to disable such behaviour?

```
<Select
  ref={r => (this.selectRef = r)}
  className="basic-single"
  classNamePrefix="select"
  onInputChange={val => {
    console.log('va', val)
    this.setState({ inputValue: val })
    }}
  inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
  options={[{ value: 'aaa', label: 'aaa bbb' }, { value: 'bbb', label: 'bbb ccc' }]}
  name="color"
/>
```

[**HERE IS A DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9rpn2ovxq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use the `onKeyDown` props and prevent the action when the use hits the space bar so nothing will be selected.

```
<Select
   ref={r => (this.selectRef = r)}
   className="basic-single"
   classNamePrefix="select"
   onInputChange={val => {
     this.setState({ inputValue: val });
   }}
   onKeyDown={e => {
     if (e.keyCode === 32 && !this.selectRef.state.inputValue) e.preventDefault();
   }}
   inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
   options={[
     { value: "aaa", label: "aaa bbb" },
     { value: "bbb", label: "bbb ccc" }
   ]}
   name="color"
 />
```

Live [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/23k43n3mjr).

Comment: Thanks, that disables spacebar in general, but changing to this does what I need `e.keyCode === 32 && !this.selectRef.state.inputValue`

Comment: Thanks @gizmo I have updated my answer in order to help future users

Comment: Can also use as so ```if(e.keyCode === 32 && !e.target.value)```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `keyCode` has been deprecated as it is used in the accepted answer.  The updated code I've written below is using React's `useRef` hook. If you care about typing you'll need to import `SelectInstance`. It's also worth mentioning that there is an automatic interaction with the `Backspace` key as well which may cause problems. Updated code below:

```
    import Select, { SelectInstance } from 'react-select';
    ...
    const selectRef = useRef<SelectInstance>(null);
    ...
    <Select
      ref={selectRef}
      onKeyDown={event => {
        // Check if the spacebar or backspace are pressed and there is no other text in the input
        if (
          (event.key === ' ' || event.key === 'Backspace') &&
          selectRef.current.state.inputValue === ''
        ) {
          // Prevent the default behavior of the spacebar
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }}
   ...
```